# Gitlab runner does not work for other users

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, runner

I have configured GitLab Runner on my server, and for me, it works without a problem. But when other developers (even if their role is maintainer) make a merge request, which is my trigger, it does not start the jobs. It shows a blank screen, which I could not figure out why.
Here is a screenshot.[image: pipelines page]

And here is the page, when I click on failed. It shows an blank page. Anyone had similar problem with a possible solution?

[image: failed blank page]